# Raspberry Pi OS /bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, 64-bit, raspberry-pi4, java-17

I need to install a recent version of java on my raspberry pi. I've installed java version 17 via sdkman. The installation seemed fine until I tried testing with `java -version`. This only puts out: `-bash: /home/pi/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java: No such file or directory`.

In reference to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists) thread, I checked that I'm running a 64bit raspberry pi os installation and that the downloaded version of java is also 64bit.

What could be the issue here?